# Spring MongoDB querying different fields using $in with array of tuples

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, repository, spring-data

Using the latest Spring data with MongoDB, I would like to retrieve all records in a collection whose fields (in my case, two) match the values in a given array of String pairs.

Given the following document structure:

```java
@Document(collection="persons")
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name="field_job_idx", def="{ 'field':1, 'job':1 }", unique=true)
})
class Person {
    String field;
    String job;
}
```

Given the following repository interface:

```java
interface PersonRepository implements Repository<Person,Long> {
    @Query("{ 'field' : { $in : ?0 } }")
    List<Person> findAnyOfTheseFields(String[] fields);    //this is easy for searching in single-valued array of fields
    @Query("{ 'job' : { $in : ?0 } }")
    List<Person> findAnyOfTheseJobs(String[] jobs);        //this is easy for searching in single-valued array of jobs

    @Query(" WHAT GOES HERE? ")
    List<Person> findAnyOfTheseUniqueFieldAndJobPairs(/* ARRAY OF PAIRS OF STRINGS */);
}
```

How can I construct the `findAnyOfTheseUniqueFieldAndJobPairs` repository method and its annotation so that I can search the `persons` collection for `Person` records whose `field` and `job` values both exist in a pair in the given array of pairs/tuples?

Can I evade the option to wrap the `field` and `job` in a wrapper class and query over a given array of instances of those wrapper classes?

I would like to do (excuse the horrible syntax, but this is how I think):

```java
repository.findAnyOfTheseUniqueFieldAndJobPairs([ ["culinary","chef"], ["law","judge"], ["athletics","goalie"]])
```

and in the repository:

```java
@Query("{ 'field','job' : { $in : ?0 } }")
List<Person> findAnyOfTheseUniqueFieldAndJobPairs(Tuple<String,String>[] fieldJobPairs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring Data Mongo `Criteria` API. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54941598/2430043):

```
Criteria[] criteriaArray = new Criteria[]{
        Criteria.where("field").is("culinary").and("job").is("chef"),
        Criteria.where("field").is("law").and("job").is("judge"),
        Criteria.where("field").is("athletics").and("job").is("goalie")
};

Criteria criteria = new Criteria().orOperator(criteriaArray);
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(criteria);
List<Person> personList = mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
```