# Spring Data Mongo Query to query with multiple fields and return in one call

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-mongodb

Firstly, the document schema am querying on, is as follows:

```
{x:10, y:"temp", z:20}
```

There are multiple other documents in the collection with the same schema as above.

Now, I have a list where each element contains, pair of values belonging to keys x and y. This can be pictured as:

```
       [{10,"temp"}, {20,"temp1"}, .....] 
keys ->  x    y        x    y
```

Now, am aware, that if I process the array in a loop and take each pair, I can construct a query like:

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("x").is(10).and("y").is("temp"))
```

This will return the document if it matches the **AND** criteria. I can query with all the pairs in the list in such a manner. But this approach will involve a high number of calls to the data base since for each pair in the list, there is a database call.

To avoid this, Is there any way I can query for all the documents  that match this **AND** criteria for each element in the list, **in a single call**, using spring data MongoDb Api? Framed differently, I want to avoid looping through the array and making multiple calls, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Criteria.orOperator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html) to return each Document that match at least one Criteria of your list.

Build your list of Criteria looping over your list

```
List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
for (item : yourList) {
  criteriaList.add(Criteria.where("x").is(item.x).and("y").is(item.y));
}
```

Build your query using `orOperator`:

```
Query.query(new Criteria.orOperator(criteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[criteriaList.size()])));
```